# Assigning another class variable value to another class Variable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I have 2 arrays in 2 different jframes(stores records as objects) and i also haves separate attributes for the 2 arrays. 
What i am trying to do is when an user enters the details in the  first form and in the radio button selection if the user selects inpatientcare, i open up the second form and i make the user enter the inpatient care details in that form. When the user clicks register in the inpatient care form  , i import the firstname , last name details which the user entered in the first form , to the second form to put in the inpatient care array (2nd array).

I have tried using get/set methods to get the value stored in the firstname, but i get an error called "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException".

Here is what i have done :-

```
     private String firstname;

     public String getfirstname() {
          return firstname;
     }
```

//  i have got the input through text field in to the firstname variable but i havent showed here.

In the second form i used the get method and tried assign in to another variable.

```
    String firstname = patient.getfirstname();
```

In the second form what i used the get method to get the value stored in the firstname variable, but my program crashes.

Inside the first form button register i do this to get the user input through data fields.

```
private void btnregisterpatientActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
  firstname=txtfirstname.getText();
```

and in the radio button selection section if the user select inpatient care and click the register button in the first form , it opens the second form (inpatient care form).

patient variable is an object of the register new class. i made it to use the methods in register_newpatient class.

Here is where i initialize patient variable.

```
   JFrame frame=new JFrame();

   Register_newpatient patient=new Register_newpatient();

  static ArrayList<patient_class>inpatientpatientlist=new ArrayList<patient_class>(); //created a seperate array for inpatient care.

  public ArrayList<patient_class> getinpatientsarray() //used a method to return the array
    {
        return inpatientpatientlist;
    }
```

Comment: I bet `patient` is `null`.

Comment: @jlordo yes, you are right, deleting my comment to avoid confusion

Comment: Again, ***where do you initialize the patient variable***??

Comment: In the class with this code, `patient.getfirstName();` please show us where you declare and initialize the patient variable, again in this class only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

patient is null, not firstname.  If firstname were null then the method would simply return null without throwing an error.  If patient is null however you get a null pointer exception because you are trying to access a method (getfirstname()) of a null object.

Comment: thx alot. I used a set method instead of get method and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
      String firstname=patient.getfirstname();
```

here patient is null so you are getting java.lang.NullPointerException. please check that you are setting it correctly.

can you post your code.so that we can help you.

Comment: Inside the first form button register i do this to get the user input through data fields.

private void btnregisterpatientActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
         
        
       
         firstname=txtfirstname.getText();


and in the radio button selection section if the user select inpatient care and click the register button in the first form , it opens the second form (inpatient care form).

Comment: @Shehan.W: update your original post with the code, not in a comment. Show where you *think* you may be initializing the patient variable.

Comment: `private void btnregisterpatientActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { firstname=txtfirstname.getText();' you can do something like this                                  'FormSecond pageSecond=new FormSecond (firstname); pageSecond.setVisible(true); dispose();'